# Flex: Select all items in an mx:List component programatically?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

To select all the items in **myList** I wrote:

```
myList.selectedItems = ['red','cyan','magenta'] ;
```

But what if I don't know about the items in the mx:list in advance? How can I select all the items in a list without specifying their names?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [selectedIndices](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#selectedIndices) property of the **List** component instead of the *selectedItems* property.

You should be able to loop through your dataset, pushing the indexes onto an array, then set selectedIndices to your array.

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this question, I just searched for this now as I had to do something similar for the first time (specifically, selecting a certain set and limiting the max selected items), but this concept works, simply manipulate the selectedIndices array.

Comment: This answer definitely works. I cannot code-format in a comment. Example code after the break: ||||

  var i:int = 0;
  for each (var s:XML in event.data.str)
  {
     checklist_datasource.addItem(s.toString());
     theChecklist.selectedIndices.push(i);
     i++;
  }

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
myList.selectedItems = (myList.dataProvider as ArrayCollection).source
```

??

I haven't tried this, but I have a feeling that this should probably work.. !!

Answer (score 0):

You may have luck accessing the child [ListBaseContentHolder](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBaseContentHolder.html) of the mx.controls.List. I've never done this myself and don't have the moment to test it, but that should be the object that contains the children of the List.